# cordova/phonegap has quick loading screen on android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

When ever I load my app on android I get a grey screen with the words "player needed"(the apps name) across the top for about a second before my app actually starts. It does not appear on the development  testing app only when I do an actual build, and then only when I start the app. If I change windows back and forth it does not appear again. How can I remove this?[example of grey screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/347pw.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this, worked for me, it's something about the MainActivity theme on Android.

In the "platforms\android" folder under your project, open the `AndroidManifest.xml` and search for `android:theme` inside the `<activity>` tag that contains `android:name="MainActivity"` and change the default value (that is `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"`) to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"`. Save the file and build your project again, the grey screen should desapear.